# Significance of quasiconvex functions over unimodal functions!

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I understand that quasiconvex functions are defined as having convex lower level sets. Unimodal functions are defined as those where the function is non-decreasing in every direction away from the minimum. Hence, quasiconvex functions are always unimodal, at least for the continuous ones.

My question is:

From a practical point of view; as in an iterative solver trying to find the minimum, is there any significance of quasiconvex functions over simply unimodal but not quasiconvex ones? Is either of them easier to prove than the other?

Comment: The function $x \mapsto \max(1,|x|)$ is convex (hence quasi convex) but not unimodal.

Comment: I am not sure how is that not unimodal?

Comment: The "uni" in unimodal refers to the fact that there is a unique local extremum. The function above has local $\min$ at all $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Would it be correct to say “weakly” unimodal in this case?

Comment: I don't know if there is any consistent notation in that regard.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't more conclusive.